# jquery file upload - publishing php variables with ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have installed blueimp jquery file upload and have run into a sticky point.

I want to get a php variable thats posted when the file is uploaded and if its exists do some php.

I have adapted the upload.class.php to do some database stuff and get the data I need.

I have then successfully managed to parse it back to my front end page but only through the exciting ajax table e.g:

```
<script id="template-download" type="text/x-tmpl">
{% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
    <tr class="template-download fade">
        {% if (file.error) { %}
          <td></td>
        <td class="name"><span>{%=file.name%}</span></td>
        <td class="size"><span>{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span></td>
        <td class="error" colspan="2"><span class="label label-important">    {%=locale.fileupload.error%}</span> {%=locale.fileupload.errors[file.error] || file.error%}</td>
        {% } else { %}
         <td class="preview">{%=file.num%}{%=file.product%}{% if (file.thumbnail_url) { %}     <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" rel="gallery" download="{%=file.name%}"><img src="{%=file.thumbnail_url%}"></a>
            {% } %}</td>
          <td class="name">
            <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" rel="{%=file.thumbnail_url&&'gallery'%}" download="{%=file.name%}">{%=file.name%}</a>
        </td>
        <td class="size"><span>{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span></td>
        <td colspan="2"></td>
    {% } %}
    <td class="delete">
        <button class="btn btn-danger" data-type="{%=file.delete_type%}" data-url="{%=file.delete_url%}">
            <i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i>
            <span>{%=locale.fileupload.destroy%}</span>
        </button>
        <input type="checkbox" name="delete" value="1">
        </td>
    </tr>
{% } %}
</script>
```

I did that to make sure: {%=file.num%}{%=file.product%}
printed and was phrasing from php which worked.

So I then want to get those to variables to trigger a php snippet elsewhere on the page outside of the "template-download" script area.

I canter work out how to do that, I can't even echo the variables if they are outside of the template-download script tags.

Any help would be greatly appreciated
Im totally lost in ajax/javascript!

Answer (score 0):

In my struggle I'm learning more and more about Ajax/Js and managed to create a div that updates :) However I'm still struggling with passing variables from js to php and vice versa!

I have a $_REQUEST["some_variable"]; at the top of my page how do I call that from the js div?

My load div is

```
$variable=$_REQUEST["some_variable"];
<script src="/js/myjsscript"></script>

<div class="container">
<script type="text/javascript">

refreshdiv();</script>
<div id="productdiv"></div>
```

I tried

```
   `refreshdiv(<? echo $variable ?>);`
```

at a long shot (I have no clue what I'm doing in js and still work on a php brain, expecting it to work. Learning very slowly :) ) But that does not work.

Update

Just tried the following instead of calling the php from the external js file

```
$variable=$_REQUEST["some_variable"];
<script src="/js/myjsscript"></script>

<div class="container">
<script type="text/javascript">
var seconds = 10;
var divid = "productdiv";
var url = "/ajaxcall_script.php?some_varaible=<? echo $variable ?>";

refreshdiv();</script>
<div id="productdiv"></div>
```

it prints out ok in the source code so I know the variable is ok. But $_REQUEST["some_varaible"] does not pick up the variable in the php?

Answer (score 0):

FIXED:
Passed the variable when the page was called in js like:

```
var nocacheurl = url+"?t="+timestamp+"&some_variable="+variable;
```

Not sure if thats the best way but my php now picks up the $_REQUEST variable and its working as expected.